# Unable to add form data in the database in Django

Tags: django, django-formwizard

Iam trying to save data from my forms to my database but somehow it is not happening. I have created  forms in one of my apps which my admin uses.I am new to Django and any help would be greatly appreciated. Below is the relevant code:

models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password

class Students(models.Model):

    username = models.CharField(max_length= 20)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    usn = models.CharField(max_length = 10, primary_key =True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

class Facultys(models.Model):

    username = models.CharField(max_length= 20)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    faculty_id= models.CharField(max_length = 10, primary_key =True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

class Admins(models.Model):

    username = models.CharField(max_length= 20)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    admin_id= models.CharField(max_length = 10, primary_key =True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from tcp.models import Login, Students, Facultys , Admins

class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=128, help_text="Please enter the name.")
    password = forms.CharField(widget = forms.PasswordInput(), help_text = 'please enter the password')
    usn= forms.CharField(max_length=10 , help_text = "Please enter the USN")

    class Meta:
        model = Students
        fields = ['username' , 'password' , 'usn']


class FacultyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=10 , help_text = "Please enter the name")
    password = forms.CharField(widget = forms.PasswordInput() , help_text = 'Please enter the password')
    faculty_id = forms.CharField(max_length=10, help_text= "Please enter your id")

    class Meta:
        model = Facultys
        fields= ['username' , 'password' , 'faculty_id']


class AdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=128, help_text="Please enter the name.")
    password = forms.CharField(widget = forms.PasswordInput(), help_text = 'please enter the password')
    admin_id= forms.CharField(max_length=10 , help_text = "Please enter the id")


    class Meta:
        model = Admins
        fields = ['username' , 'password' , 'admin_id']
```

views.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.shortcuts import render
from tcp.forms import LoginForm,StudentForm,AdminForm,FacultyForm
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password


def indexx(request):
    return render(request, 'tcp/firstlook.html')


def student_signup(request):
    form = StudentForm()
    if request.method =='POST':
        form = StudentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit = True)

            return index(request)
        else:
            print form.errors

    return render(request , 'tcp/student_login.html', {'form':form})

def faculty(request):
    form =FacultyForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form =FacultyForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit = True)
            return indexz(request)
        else:
            print form.errors
    return render(request , 'tcp/faculty_login.html', {'form': form})

def admin(request):
    form=AdminForm()
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=AdminForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit =True)
            return indexzz(request)
        else:
            print form.errors
    return render(request , 'tcp/admin.html' , {'form' :form})
```

Here is my admin.py file where i have registered my models into the site administration

admin.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Placement_Department,Spc, Login,Students, Facultys, Admins


admin.site.register(Login)
admin.site.register(Students)
admin.site.register(Facultys)
admin.site.register(Admins)
```

But my Student form is saving the data in the database.

Comment: Are you trying to make user accounts like this?

Comment: Yes The forms will take in the required details and save the data and I do not want to use UserForm

Comment: Take a look at this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/

The way youre doing it wont encrypt any of the passwords in your database, leaving your information insecure. It also won't allow your users to log in or be authenticated through django's built in system

Comment: Thank You . But why is it not storing form data in the database for admins and facultys but storing for students?. I am ignoring password encryption for now.

Comment: Are you getting any errors

Comment: No, Thanks. I went through the link and understood where was i  going wrong.